# How can I create a WSO2 BPM as a service?

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I wanted to know:
How to create the service of the deployed bpm in WSO2 BPS server?
As I want to trigger this whole BPM as a service from my customised HTML UI.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you mean BPMN workflow as "deployed bpm". After deploying BPMN in WSO2 BPS, You need to use BPMN Rest API to start an instance of the process and to manage and update necessary tasks. Please refer [BPMN REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/BPMN+REST+API) for detailed information

Thanks,
Mili